# Is there any way to pass data extension values to salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a Data Extension that stores user details like FirstName,LastName and Email.
Is there any way that allows us to pass these values to our Salesforce CRM. Maybe as a record in Contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your use case, but generally you have two options:

**Option 1:**

Use Journey Builder Sales & Service Cloud activities to create/update data on Salesforce CRM. You need to have the Marketing Cloud Connector.

PS: don't forget to link your DE in Data Designer to be able to use it in your Journey.

**Option 2:**

Use a CloudPage to update data on CRM by using `CreateSalesforceObject` or  `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` functions. Check the doc for more information:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm

Comment: Thanks Rachid for the help.