# Data transfer from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Does anyone know how to transfer data from the Data Extension (some field values) to some object in Salesforce?
I try to do it through Journey.

Comment: Hope this helps https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282083/is-there-any-way-to-pass-data-extension-values-to-salesforce-crm

Comment: Oops, didn't check that I've already answered this question three years ago. Thanks for sharing @VishalKumarCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give more details. But, if you have the MC Connect in place, you can use Journey Builder Sales and Service Cloud Activities.

Ex:

**Object activity**:

> Creates or updates a standard Salesforce object record, such as a
> lead, task, or custom object, when a contact in the journey reaches
> this activity. Use this activity to create or update a standard
> Salesforce object record, such as a lead or task, or a custom object
> record.

You can also use **UpdateSingleSalesforceObject** & **CreateSalesforceObject** with AMPScript.

**References:**

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_sales_service_cloud_activities.htm&type=5

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createsalesforceobject.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject.html

Comment: It is too nice of you to answer these poorly written questions :-)

Comment: I’ve been away for too long, I’m answering everything I can to get back the mechanisms :(

Comment: Thank you for the help!